# SprinBoot JpaRepository findByEmail not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a SpringBoot application and trying to verify some info that I loaded to DB and check that with unit tests. I cannot seem to get findByEmail working

I have a entity `user` that is something like

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name", length=50, nullable=false, unique=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(length=50)
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password", length=50, nullable=false, unique=false)
    private String password;
...
}
```

`userRepository` like this. I've tried both with `@Query("SELECT * FROM user u WHERE u.email=:email")` and without. Also returning `List<User>` or just user. The result here is always either null or an error.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Interface UserService

```java
public interface UserService {

    public List<User> list();

    public User loadUserByEmail(String email);
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> list() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public User loadUserByEmail(String email) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        return user;
    }
}
```

UserServiceUnitTest

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void recordCreation() {
        List<User> users = userService.list();
        Assert.assertEquals(users.size(), 3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserFindByEmail() {
        // First user test
        User user = userService.loadUserByEmail("mail@mail.com");
        Assert.assertEquals(user.getName(), "User1");
    }
}
```

applications.properties

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

What am I doing wrong here? Result is always either Null or an error and I know for a fact the email exists and is loaded in the DB because I have mysqlworkbench open and I'm looking at it. Also the first unitTest passes and confirms there are 3 rows in the table.

Comment: as you show/describe: it should work! The problem must be in the data/parameters/your assumptions (e.g. the state/instance of db, findByEmail is *case sensitive*...)

Comment: Looks good, try to enable debug output to check what query is sent https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Comment: All things seem ok, that's weird, can you try to add `@Transactional ` at the top of `UserServiceUnitTest`?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov sql debut output ends with `where
    user0_.email=?` and then throws NullPointerException. Not sure if that's where the issue is?  Everything else appears ok, cases and everything

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali same thing happens as my reply above

Comment: What type is the database column for `email`. Is it a `varchar` or a `char`.. I suspect the latter.

Comment: @M.Deinum and everyone else, thank you for your help. I solved it. Apparently I missed the very obvious, which was JPA creates table in a different order than I define them in the Entity Classes for some reason. I was inserting on `Data.sql` in the same order I defined attributes on `entity` and they were being created in another order.  It was my first time using it and I was unaware of this

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and eventually accept it so others can see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed the very obvious, which was JPA/Hibernate creates columns in a different order than I define them in the Entity Classes for some reason.

I was inserting on Data.sql in the same order I defined attributes on entity and they were being created in another order. It was my first time using it and I was unaware of this

You can check official sources [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=974532) and [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2396344)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was connection string. The connection string in Application.yml was pointing to incorrect schema (database)